# How can I rewrite my code without hardcoding the names of the attributes?

Tags: typescript, refactoring, ramda.js

I'm working with Ramda.js and Typescript. For getting the some value from object I use [lensPath](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensPath).

Example:

```
export interface Store {
    foo: {
       bar: string;
    };
}

const store: Store = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'baz'
  }
};
const fooBarLens = R.lensPath(['foo', 'bar']);
```

Unfortunately, if I will do some refactoring via my WebStorm and will rename the attribute `bar` to `baz` in class `Store`, then function `fooBarLens` will stop working.

But if before refactoring  I will rewrite the function `fooBarLens` like:

```
const fooBarLens = (s) => s.foo.bar;
```

then the refactoring would work correctly.

How can I rewrite using `lensPath` and other Ramda functions without hardcoding the names of the attributes and avoid the refactoring problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a wonderful solution for this.  It's one of the trade-offs for using a string-based API.  Many refactoring tools I've seen also offer to rename the property in strings and comments, and that may be enough, especially if it walks you through such strings one-by-one and offers you the decision.

But one technique makes this much easier: centralizing the handling for your data model in a single module.  If you have to change this sort of code all over your code-base, it can get ugly:

```
const phone = view(lensPath(['contact', 'phones', 'primary'], user);
```

It's a lot easier if your user module exposes `phoneLens` and your code is just

```
const phone = view(phoneLens, user)
```

Then, when your model changes, in that one location you can switch

```
const phoneLens = lensPath(['contact', 'phone', 'primary'])
```

to

```
const phoneLens = lensPath(['contacts', 'telephone', 0])
```

with no change to the rest of your code.

---

Do remember that in JavaScript, the `store.foo.bar` format is not actually the core.  It is just syntactic sugar over the more fundamental `store['foo']['bar']` version.  Refactoring tools may one day catch up with this understanding, if they haven't already done so.